# Run avdmanager with sudo

Tags: linux, command-line, avd-manager

I am running `avdmanager create avd` from my python script that I start with `sudo -E` to make my script be able to do priveldged stuff. But for some reason avdmanager created AVD inside `/root/.android/avd`, but not inside `/home/user/.android/avd`. How does it know that it is being run with sudo? I am really confused. Please, help me to figure this out.

Comment: Your question isn't quite clear.. you say you run the command with sudo and questioning when it is being run in /root?

Comment: @44yu5h Yes, but `-E` should have retained the user's environment. The question is indeed unclear but I think it's about why it didn't.

Comment: Maybe you should ask this question on superuser. Also check this out https://superuser.com/questions/636283/how-to-allow-user-to-preserve-environment-with-sudo

Comment: @ChanganAuto Yeah, my wording maybe wasn't quite good. Then, forget about python script that I mentioned. The problem is the following: I run `sudo -E avdmanager create avd` from terminal as a user, but it puts new device inside `/root/.android/avd` for some reason.

Comment: @44yu5h Thank you for the link, but this is not my case actually, because I don't have any errors regarding environment preserving.

Comment: Cross-posted to Super User: https://superuser.com/q/1780670/356789